# WebDriver gets text from span tag

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a span tag like this:

```html
<div class="row-flex">
  <span class="icon-arrow-down-outline rotate-v"></span>
  <span class="bmi-value ng-binding">22</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the value 22 of this span tag, so I write java code like this:

```
WebElement spanValue = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='bmi-value ng-binding']"));        
String value = spanValue.getText();
```

but it always returns an empty string. What is missing?

Comment: It's been a while since I last used an xpath selector but if I recall you can't include a space within the selector. `By.cssSelector(".bmi-value.ng-binding")` might work instead?

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple elements in the page that can be located with that locator? If that's the case, and if you have control over the HTML, you could add an id to the element you are interested in, like this: `<span ìd="age" class="bmi-value ng-binding">22</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are several span elements with the same class on your site,
you can try to be more specific like this:

```
WebElement spanValue = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row-flex']/span[@class='bmi-value ng-binding']"));        
String value = spanValue.getText();
```

Comment: yeah, just found out there is another HTML part with the same div and span, but it's hidden, so I didn't notice. They are exactly identical, so for now, I just use findElements and get index. Thanks all for your answers

Comment: @LouisT working with indexes is not the best approach, since you are prone to changes in the structure of the website, for example if the developers put another of these spans in the code, then you have to fix your queries all the time...

Comment: yeah I know, I found a solution, still use findElement and getAttribute("textContent") and it returns the exact value of the visible span